# django unable to saved forms in database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm learning django and I'm trying to **save the form** using POST method and found its working fine, I'M not able to see the saved message in database(**form is not submitted**)

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def description_as_list(self):
        return self.description.split('\n')

class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

Forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'description')

editPostedForm = modelformset_factory(Post, PostForm)

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('comments',)
        exclude = ('title',)
```

Views.py

```
def detail(request, id):
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    comments = posts.comment_set.all()
    forms = CommentForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=posts)
        print form
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
        else:
          print form.errors
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    return render(request, "detail_post.html", {'forms':forms,'posts': posts,'comments':comments})
```

Why is the post message is not being saved. I got status code 200 in console, also i get the entered data, but the form is not being saved...Any help is much appreciated

Comment: [<Comment: 1st_blog>]........but did not save data..

Comment: Then your form should have errors. What does `form.errors` say? `title` should be required, right?

Comment: The logic goes through form_is.valid block....but does not save form...So no errors is being displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your form excludes `title` field, but it's required according to `Comment` definition. You need to give the `title` to comment instance then save it:

```
def detail(request, id):
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    comments = posts.comment_set.all()
    forms = CommentForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST,instance=posts)
        print form
        if form.is_valid():
            # create a comment instance in memory first
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            # fill out the title field
            comment.title = posts
            comment.save()
        else:
          print form.errors
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    return render(request, "detail_post.html", {'forms':forms,'posts': posts,'comments':comments})
```

Also, I don't know why you use plural form for one instance, like `posts` should be `post` because you use `objects.get()`, make your code more readable would save some confusion for other people.